# Why nextcloud does not find the database in Docker?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, mariadb, nextcloud

I build my Home-Server on a raspberry pi and wanted to install nextcloud with Docker on it.
But nextcloud don't find the mariadb.

What's wrong?

```
  db:
    image: jsurf/rpi-mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci    
    volumes:
      - /media/data/mySQL:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Foo12345
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=Foo123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud


  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:apache
    volumes:
      - /media/data/nextCloud:/var/www/html/data
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Foo12345
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=Foo123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:cloud.domain.com"
```

NextCloud starts but if I try to set the admin-User comes the Error: 
[image]

The Container of the mariadb has the IP 172.21.0.4 so I think there is somthing wrong with the link. But what?

(172.21.0.5 is the IP of the NextCloud-Container)

Comment: what happens if you delete `link` section and add `depends_on: - db` ?

Comment: @michalk Exactly the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had to execute this on mysql (mariadb) CLI in order to finalise the installation:

```
CREATE USER 'nextcloud'@'nextcloud-app.nextcloud_app-tier' IDENTIFIED BY 'nextcloud';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nextcloud. * TO 'nextcloud'@'nextcloud-app.nextcloud_app-tier' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Where:

- nextcloud-app, is the name for the nextcloud container
- nextcloud_app-tier, is the docker network used

It may help others.

Sources:

https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/installing-nextcloud-docker/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by changing the user and root password by removing strange characters like `_:\`